GEOSException in dev container for geodjango with postgis for python 3.12
I'm trying to setup a dev container to develop a geodjango application.
The dev container spins up and runs but when browsing in the admin to the model overview that contains a PointField, I get the following error message:
Error message:
GEOSException at /admin/phyiscal_assets/plant/
Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSWKBReader_read_r".
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8002/admin/phyiscal_assets/plant/
Django Version: 5.0.7
Exception Type: GEOSException
Exception Value:    
Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSWKBReader_read_r".
Exception Location: /workspaces/django-test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/prototypes/errcheck.py, line 33, in check_geom
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.options.changelist_view
Python Executable:  /workspaces/django-test/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.12.4
Python Path:    
['/workspaces/django-test/src/XXX',
 '/usr/local/lib/python312.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.12',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
 '/workspaces/django-test/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages',
 '/workspaces/django-test/src']
Server time:    Wed, 31 Jul 2024 15:09:24 +0000

models.py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models #as gis_models

class Plant(models.Model):
    """Model representing a plant."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.PointField()  # lat and long point fields

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.name

admin.py:
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from .models import Plant

@admin.register(Plant)
class PlantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'city')

The DEV Container (VS Code) is created via:
devcontainer.json:
{
  "name": "Python 3",
  "build": {
    "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    "context": "..",
    "args": {
      "NODE_VERSION": "lts/*",
      "POETRY_VERSION": "1.8.3",
      "NOX_VERSION": "2024.4.15"
    }
  },
  "customizations": {
    "vscode": {
      "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
        "lextudio.restructuredtext-pack"
      ],
      "settings": {
          "redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
          "github.gitProtocol": "ssh",
          "github.copilot.advanced": {},
          "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light Modern",
          "notebook.output.scrolling": true,
          "notebook.output.wordWrap": true,
          "notebook.output.textLineLimit": 200,
          "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
          "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
          "editor.inlineSuggest.showToolbar": "always",
          "editor.formatOnSave": true,
          "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
          "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": "explicit"
          },
          "black-formatter.args": [
            "--line-length",
            "99",
            "--skip-magic-trailing-comma"
          ],
          "editor.rulers": [99, 120],
          "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
            "editorRuler.foreground": "#ff4081"
          },
          "flake8.args": ["--max-line-length=100"],
          "[python]": {
            "editor.formatOnType": true,
            "editor.insertSpaces": true,
            "editor.tabSize": 4,
            "editor.formatOnSave": true,
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter"
          },
          "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off",
          "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
        
          "[django-html]": {
            "djlint.enableLinting": true,
            "djlint.profile": "django",
            "editor.quickSuggestions": {
              "other": true,
              "comments": true,
              "strings": true
            }
          },
          "black-formatter.importStrategy": "fromEnvironment",
          "git.autofetch": true
      }
    }
  },
  "postCreateCommand": "bash ./.devcontainer/post-install.sh",
  "runArgs": ["--network=host"], //-p=3000:3000 
  "remoteUser": "root",
  "features": {
    "github-cli": "latest"
  },
  "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/workspaces/django-test,type=bind",
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/django-test"
}

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-slim
ARG POETRY_VERSION="none"
ARG NOX_VERSION="none"

ENV DJANGO_ENV=${DJANGO_ENV} \
  # python:
  PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
  PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
  # pip:
  PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
  PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
  PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
  # poetry:
  POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=false \
  POETRY_CACHE_DIR='/var/cache/pypoetry'

ENV POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=1 \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/tmp/poetry_cache

# extend deb sources
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y software-properties-common

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    bash \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    gettext \
    git \
    wget \
    binutils \
    libproj-dev \
    python3-dev \
    geos-bin \
    libpq-dev gdal-bin libgdal-dev
    
RUN pip3 install setuptools -U

# Poetry
RUN if [ "${POETRY_VERSION}" != "none" ]; then \
    pip3 install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}; \
fi

# Nox
RUN if [ "${NOX_VERSION}" != "none" ]; then \
  pip3 install nox-poetry nox==${NOX_VERSION};\
fi

RUN pip3 install psycopg2 -U

post-install.sh:
#!/bin/bash

export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

gdal_version = bash -c "ogrinfo --version | cut -d, -f1 |  sed 's/.* //'"
poetry add "gdal==$gdal_version"

poetry install

pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry]
name = "XXX"
version = "0.0.8"
description = "XXX"
authors = ["XXX"]
license = "MIT"
readme = "README.md"
homepage = "XXX"
repository = "XXX"
documentation = "XXX"
classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
]

[tool.poetry.urls]
Changelog = "XXX"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
click = ">=8.0.1"
django = "^5.0.6"
uvicorn = "^0.29.0"
gunicorn = "^22.0.0"
psycopg2 = "^2.9.9"
djangorestframework = "^3.15.1"
django-filter = "^24.2"
markdown = "^3.6"
django-location-field = "^2.7.3"
numpy = "^2.0.1"
gdal = "3.9.1"
djlint = "^1.34.1"
psycopg2-binary = "^2.9.9"
pyproj = "^3.6.1"
pandas = "^2.2.2"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
Pygments = ">=2.10.0"
bandit = ">=1.7.4"
black = ">=21.10b0"
coverage = {extras = ["toml"], version = ">=6.2"}
darglint = ">=1.8.1"
flake8 = ">=4.0.1"
flake8-bugbear = ">=21.9.2"
flake8-docstrings = ">=1.6.0"
flake8-rst-docstrings = ">=0.2.5"
furo = ">=2021.11.12"
isort = ">=5.10.1"
mypy = ">=0.930"
pep8-naming = ">=0.12.1"
pre-commit = ">=2.16.0"
pre-commit-hooks = ">=4.1.0"
pytest = ">=6.2.5"
pyupgrade = ">=2.29.1"
safety = ">=1.10.3"
sphinx = ">=4.3.2"
sphinx-autobuild = ">=2021.3.14"
sphinx-click = ">=3.0.2"
typeguard = ">=2.13.3"
xdoctest = {extras = ["colors"], version = ">=0.15.10"}
myst-parser = {version = ">=0.16.1"}
# djlint = "^1.34.1"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
XXX = "XXX.__main__:main"

[tool.coverage.paths]
source = ["src", "*/site-packages"]
tests = ["tests", "*/tests"]

[tool.coverage.run]
branch = true
source = ["XXX", "tests"]

[tool.coverage.report]
show_missing = true
fail_under = 100

[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
force_single_line = true
lines_after_imports = 2

[tool.mypy]
strict = true
warn_unreachable = true
pretty = true
show_column_numbers = true
show_error_context = true

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

Any idea where to start? I tried to update geos and gdal packages but without success.

I think it has something todo with the database. I could fix it by

removing the model
making migrations and executing them,
3 adding the model again and creating new migrations.

